# Package erros problem with php 7.4 install on Centos 7.8

Tags: php, centos7, php-7

I'm having issues with Centos 7.8 and PHP7 I've gone through Stack Overlfow and found some similar posts but am not getting a answer for my issue. I have php 5.6 and when I try to install php 74 I get the errors down below. I've tried installing the Required file but it just throws another error saying that it requires that same file.

Error:

```
Package: php-mcrypt-7.1.33-10.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.33-10.el7.remi
           Removing: php-common-5.6.40-23.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-23.el7.remi
           Updated By: php-common-7.4.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.12-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-48.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-18.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-22.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-22.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.1.33-9.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.33-9.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.1.33-10.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.33-10.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.2.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.2.33-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.2.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.2.34-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.3.23-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.23-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.3.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.24-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.4.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.11-1.el7.remi
Error: Package: php-recode-7.3.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.24-1.el7.remi
           Removing: php-common-5.6.40-23.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-23.el7.remi
           Updated By: php-common-7.4.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.12-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-48.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-18.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-22.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-22.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.1.33-9.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.33-9.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.1.33-10.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.33-10.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.2.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.2.33-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.2.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.2.34-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.3.23-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.23-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.3.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.24-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-7.4.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.11-1.el7.remi
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have various php repositories (remi-php71, remi-php72...) enabled, only keep the one you want

As explained by the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

```
yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php74
```

> Package: php-mcrypt-7.1.33-10.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)

The [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) extension is deprecated and have been removed from **PHP 7.2**

Also read: [About libmcrypt and php-mcrypt](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

> Error: Package: php-recode-7.3.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)

The [recode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.recode.php) extension is deprecated and have been removed from **PHP 7.4**

So you have to remove these extensions before upgrading, and if you "really" need them, you cannot upgrade.

```
yum remove php-recode php-mcrypt
```

Notice: php-pecl-mcrypt and php-pecl-recode are available for legacy applications, but are discouraged and won't be supported.